# OpenAI gymSuperMarioBros object has no attribute 'render_mode'

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to using stable-baselines3 PPO model to train a agent to play gym-super-mario-bros,but when it runs, here is the basic model train code:

```
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym_super_mario_bros
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
import gym


env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)


tensorboard_log = r'./tensorboard_log/'

model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1,tensorboard_log = tensorboard_log)
model.learn(total_timesteps=25000)
model.save("mario_model")
```

and i got this error:

```
Using cpu device
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-f912901bbdee> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 
      5 #model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose=1,tensorboard_log = tensorboard_log)
----> 6 model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1)
      7 model.learn(total_timesteps=25000)
      8 model.save("mario_model")

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shimmy/openai_gym_compatibility.py in __init__(self, env_id, make_kwargs, env)
     88 
     89         self.metadata = getattr(self.gym_env, "metadata", {"render_modes": []})
---> 90         self.render_mode = self.gym_env.render_mode
     91         self.reward_range = getattr(self.gym_env, "reward_range", None)
     92         self.spec = getattr(self.gym_env, "spec", None)

AttributeError: 'SuperMarioBrosEnv' object has no attribute 'render_mode'
```

I'm using colab,
stable-baselines3 version is 2.0.0
gym-super-mario-bros 7.4.0
gym 0.23.1
I tried to install old version of stable-baselines3, but got this:

```
Collecting stable-baselines3==1.5.0
  Using cached stable_baselines3-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (177 kB)
Collecting gym==0.21 (from stable-baselines3==1.5.0)
  Using cached gym-0.21.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am a beginner in reinforcement learning, hope you can help me.

Comment: The github page contains a requirements.txt file (which is 5 years old :/) where it states it uses quite old versions of all packages. Now, it is suggested that any version above the recommended version would work, though since this is a very old requirements file, I would suggest to try and use these versions instead. And for sure need an older version of stable baselines 3, the newest version runs with gymnasium instead of gym

Comment: Can you tell me how to install old version Stable Baselines3? When i tried to install the old version of SB3, i always got "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully." error. @Lexpj

Comment: How did you do it in the first place? Did you uninstall the newest version first?

Comment: I solved it by downgrade setuptools and user wheel 

pip install --user wheel==0.38.0
pip install setuptools==65.5.0

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in synching both nes-py(8.2.1) and gym(0.26.0+)

The recommendation is to use

```
gym==0.21.0
stable_baselines==1.16.0
```

The problem with installing the above requirements is that it does doenot work with setuptools 0.67+ and wheel>0.40.0

so the suggestion is to use

```
!pip install setuptools==65.5.0 "wheel<0.40.0"
```

The complete solutions is to run the following commands:

```
!pip install nes-py
!pip install gym-super-mario-bros==7.3.0
!pip install setuptools==65.5.0 "wheel<0.40.0"
!pip install gym==0.21.0
!pip install stable-baselines3[extra]==1.6.0
```